# ¿Como puedo eliminar totalmente un war desplegado en Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, war

Cuando voy a la parte de Diagnostico del `tomcat version 8,` y hago `click` en la función de `"Halla fallos de memoria"`, me envía este mensaje:

Las siguientes aplicaciones `web` fueron paradas (recargadas, replegadas), pero sus clases de las ejecuciones previas aún se encuentran en memoria, causando así un fallo de memoria (usa un perfilador para confirmarlo):

```
<br>
/BCK-1<br>
/BCK-2<br>
/BCK-2<br>
/BCK-2<br>
/BCK-1<br>
/BCK-2<br>
/BCK-1<br>
/BCK-1<br>
```

Comment: En ese caso deberás apagar el tomcat para que te deje borrarlo completamente, o esperar a que el garbage collector limpie toda la memoria que usaba esa aplicación

Comment: @shop350 Use el comando sudo service tomcat restart y ya no me muestra ese mensaje

Comment: Busca en la carpeta del tomcat y donde se guardan todas los war que se despliegan eliminalo directamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comenta AndyC, primero deten Tomcat, ve a webapps y borra la carpeta de tu proyecto y vuelve a iniciar el servicio.

Answer (score 2):

1. Deten el Tomcat
2. Ve a la carpeta webapps y borra tus aplicaciones o todas menos: host-manager, manager y ROOT.
3. Ve a la carpeta work y borra el contenido para que se limpien los temporales